# how can I implement the tf-idf and cosine similarity in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

How can I implement the tf-idf and cosine similarity in Lucene? I'm using Lucene 4.2. The program that I've created does not use tf-idf and Cosine similaryty, it only uses TopScoreDocCollector.

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.id.IndonesianAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.index.*;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;

public class IndexMysqlDBStemming {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // 1. Create Index From Database
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_haiquran", "root", "");

    IndonesianAnalyzer analyzer = new IndonesianAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42);
    //StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42);
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_42, "result", analyzer);

    Directory INDEX_DIR = new RAMDirectory();

    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_42, analyzer);
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(INDEX_DIR, config);

    String query = "SELECT * FROM ayat";
    java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);

    while (result.next()) {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new Field("NO_INDEX_AYAT", result.getString("NO_INDEX_AYAT"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field("NO_SURAT", result.getString("NO_SURAT"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field("NO_AYAT", result.getString("NO_AYAT"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field("TEXT_INDO", result.getString("TEXT_INDO"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field("TEXT_ARAB", result.getString("TEXT_ARAB"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        writer.updateDocument(new Term("NO_INDEX_AYAT", result.getString("NO_INDEX_AYAT")), document);

    }

    writer.close();


    // 2. Query
    System.out.println("Enter your search keyword in here : ");
    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = bufferRead.readLine();
    String querystr = args.length > 0 ? args[0] :s;

    try {
        System.out.println(parser.parse(querystr)+"\n"); //amenit
        System.out.println();

    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        // Exception
    }

    Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_42, "TEXT_INDO", analyzer).parse(querystr);

    // 3. Search

    int hitsPerPage = 10;
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(INDEX_DIR);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
    searcher.search(q, collector);
    ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;

    // 4. Display results

    System.out.println("Found : " + hits.length + " hits.");

    System.out.println("No" + " ID " + "\t" + " Surat " + "\t" + " No Ayat " + "\t" + " Terjemahan Ayat " + "\t" + " Teks Arab ");

    for (int i=0; i<hits.length; i++) {
       int docID = hits[i].doc;
       Document d = searcher.doc(docID);

       System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + d.get("NO_INDEX_AYAT") + "\t" + d.get("NO_SURAT") + "\t" + d.get("NO_AYAT")+ 
               "\t" + d.get("TEXT_INDO") + "\t" + d.get("TEXT_ARAB"));

    }

    reader.close();        
  }
}
```

How can I display the results of the calculation using tf-idf and cosine similarity?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186002/8430173

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless there is something I'm missing, you're already done.  Well done!

The similarity algorithm being used by default is the [DefaultSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/DefaultSimilarity.html), but most of the documentation (and logic) you'll find in it's base class [TFIDFSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html).

And TFIDFSimilarity is indeed an implementation of a TF-IDF and Cosine similarity scoring model.

Comment: thank you femtoRgon. Can you give examples of program code using TFIDFSimilarity and DefaultSimilarity?

I've tried to calculate TF-idf but do not use the module in Lucene, this is my code:



but less effective because its value is inserted into a variable, how to use code examples and DefaultSimilarity TFIDFSimilarity?

Comment: thank you femtoRgon. Can you give examples of program code using TFIDFSimilarity and DefaultSimilarity? I've tried to calculate TF-idf but do not use the module in Lucene : TermFreqVector tfv = ir.getTermFreqVector(docNum, "TEXT_INDO");
            String terms[] = tfv.getTerms();
            int termCount = terms.length;
            int freqs[] = tfv.getTermFrequencies();            
            for(int t=0; t < termCount; t++) {
                double weightTerms =  (freqs[t] * (Math.log10(293/termCount) + 1)); 

but less effective because its value is inserted into a var

Comment: I'm afraid I may not understand what you are trying to do.  Lucene applies a scoring algorithm, agreeing well with your specification, by default.  Upon querying, you get an array of [`ScoreDoc`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ScoreDoc.html)s, from which you can get the score via `ScoreDoc.score`, or in your case, as you loop through `hits`, you can just get `hits[i].score`.