# Do Lucene(java framework) by default calculates the tf-idf and cosine similarity of a document against the term?

Tags: java, lucene, search-engine, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I am developing a search engine based application and was working on Lucene java framework, i am being confused by the score functionality by default provided by lucene i.e do the score functionality implements by default tf-idf and cosine similarity or do we have to do something else ?

```
public class LuceneTester {

String indexDir =  "C:\\Users\\hamda\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\luceneDemo\\Index";
String dataDir =  "C:\\Users\\hamda\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\luceneDemo\\Data";
Indexer indexer;
Searcher searcher;
public static void main(String[] args) {
  LuceneTester tester;
  try {
     tester = new LuceneTester();
    tester.createIndex();
     tester.search("DataGuides");
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

private void createIndex() throws IOException{

  indexer = new Indexer(indexDir);
  int numIndexed;
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  
  numIndexed = indexer.createIndex(dataDir, new TextFileFilter());
  long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  indexer.close();
  System.out.println(numIndexed+" File indexed, time taken: "
     +(endTime-startTime)+" ms");       
}
```

i am getting the Document score in the end of the search function below

```
private void search(String searchQuery) throws IOException, ParseException{
  searcher = new Searcher(indexDir);
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  TopDocs hits = searcher.search(searchQuery);
  long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

  System.out.println(hits.totalHits +
     " documents found. Time :" + (endTime - startTime));
  for(ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) {
     Document doc = searcher.getDocument(scoreDoc);
        System.out.println(scoreDoc.score+" File: "
        + doc.get(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH));
  }
  searcher.close();
}
}
```

I have googled it and found this:
[how can I implement the tf-idf and cosine similarity in Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203118/how-can-i-implement-the-tf-idf-and-cosine-similarity-in-lucene)
Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Lucene 6.0, the default similarity implementation is [BM25Similarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html), which implements [BM25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25).

If you want to use the old standard similarity implementation, use [ClassicSimilarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/ClassicSimilarity.html).

For a comparison of the two, you might check out:

- Doug Turnbull's [BM25 The Next Generation of Lucene Relevance](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/)
- ElasticSearch's [BM25 vs Lucene Default Similarity](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-bm-vs-lucene-default-similarity)

Answer (score 0):

As i was going through some details in http://lucene.apache.org/, i found out that lucene scoring model by default use this class DefaultSimilarity http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html which extends the TFIDFSimilarity class, http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html
So in there documentation it is stated that scoring model by default implements tf-idf and cosine similarity. Any ways i may be wrong, so you can correct me :)